# Display div when inline style none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a submit button that uses Gravity Forms to conditionally show or hide the button.

When the button is shown the code looks like: `<button class="button gform_button" id="gform_submit_button_1" style="">`

When the button is not shown the code looks like: `<button class="button gform_button" id="gform_submit_button_1" style="display: none;">`

So, what I wanted to do was display a div when the button is not displayed or has the inline style `display: none`.

I thought I could do something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1');
    if (x.style.display = 'none') {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is a hidden div that we can show with JavaScript</div>
```

This shows `div1` when the page loads, but when `style=""` the div does not hide. When the condition is true and `style=""` the page does not refresh, which is probably the issue. Is there a way to tweak things so that when `style=""` `div1` is not shown?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What do you want to show when the `button` is invisible? And when does the `myFunction` executed?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. There are two `display: none` elements - button and div1, not sure what you want to get exactly.

Comment: In JS, `=` means assignment, whereas `==` or `===` means comparing for equality. So try `if (x.style.display === 'none')`.

Comment: Hey there, when `gform_submit_button_1` is showing I'd like 'div1` to be hidden. When `gform_submit_button_1` is not showing, I'd like `div1` to show. I am not calling that function, I just wanted it to execute when the inline style on the button changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also simply add a Gravity Form HTML field with your alternative div inside.  Then use conditional logic to show it when the submit button is hidden.

Comment: So, I hadn't thought about this approach...however, there is no conditional logic for that targets the submit button. I was able to make it work on the field though. So, initially, I'm hiding the submit button unless the field matches a number. But I can also do the same thing, but opposite...show an html field unless the field matches a number. This definitely works :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x.style.display = 'none')
```

This should be:

```
if (x.style.display == 'none')
```

otherwise, the `if` statement will return `true` in all cases, and the `x.style.display` property will be always `'none'`.

As in the comment section, `=` is used for assignment, `==` for value comparison whereas `===` is used for type and value comparison.

And for this,

> When the condition is true and style="" the page does not refresh,
> which is probably the issue.

you should call the function somewhere so it can be executed after the page loading.

Comment: The code (which checks style properties) should have two event listeners:
1. On load
2. On some change

That being said

Comment: Exactly! @str1ng

Comment: By the way, your answer is not really full-filled and not really clarified. I will edit it, so if you see it as suitable edit please, accept it

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As the queue for editing of answer from @Dream Bold is full this is my answer regarding to this question based on the previous Answer.
Basically clarification

Following line of code:

```
if (x.style.display = 'none')
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (x.style.display == 'none')
```

Main difference is the operator used (`==`). In the first case by using "`=`" the `if` statement will always return `true`, and the `x.style.display` property will be always `'none'`.

As in the comment section, `=` is used for assignment, `==` for value comparison whereas `===` is used for type and value comparison.

To learn more about expressions and operators: [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

And regarding for following requirement

> When the condition is true and style="" the page does not refresh,
> which is probably the issue.

The problem in this is that the code is not executed.
You should first create function, then by adding [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or setting `action` which would call the previously created function so it can be executed after the page loading.

My suggestion is to use `window.onload` + another event listener/action attribute on element

Like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
var x = document.getElementById("gform_submit_button_1");
if(x.style.display == "none"){
alert("Display of x is none");
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
}
else{
alert("Display of x is not none");
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
x.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Comment: I added this code and the div shows, but it doesn't hide.

Comment: @JoshRodgers Well, you did not add event listener (additional one). Mainly, when you load site (enter it) the code inside of this function executes (only once!!!) -> your button is hidden whereas `if(x.style.display == "none")` equals to true which will result in `div1` showing. As I've stated in answer (I couldn't give you correct code because I don't know what is triggering button to be shown), you need to add another event listener.

Comment: @JoshRodgers Also, there's another possible approach -> setting initially div1's display property to block and button's display property to none. After it, you need to just write one function (which will be triggered by action), in that function you need to set div's display property to none and button's property to block. (Also debatable as per your requirements -> this will be ok if your site doesn't make button disappear again after X amount of time after being the button is being shown or div being hidden)